# Pandas groupy - Can I use it for different functions on different sets of rows?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, aggregation

I have a large pandas dataframe with many different types of observations that need different models applied to them. One column is which model to apply, and that can be mapped to a python function which accepts a dataframe and returns a dataframe. One approach would be just doing 3 steps:

1. split dataframe into n dataframes for n different models
2. run each dataframe through each function
3. concatenate output dataframes at the end

This just ends up not being super flexible particularly as models are added and removed. Looking at groupby it seems like I should be able to leverage that to make this look much cleaner code-wise, but I haven't been able to find a pattern that does what I'd like.

Also because of the size of this data, using apply isn't particularly useful as it would drastically slow down the runtime.

Quick example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"model":["a","b","a"],"a":[1,5,8],"b":[1,4,6]})
def model_a(df):
    return df["a"] + df["b"]
def model_b(df):
    return df["a"] - df["b"]
model_map = {"a":model_a,"b":model_b}
results = df.groupby("model")...
```

The expected result would look like [2,1,14]. Is there an easy way code-wise to do this? Note that the actual models are much more complicated and involve potentially hundreds of variables with lots of transformations, this is just a toy example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby/apply`:

- `x.name` contains the name of the group, here `a` and `b`
- `x` contains the sub dataframe

```
df['r'] = df.groupby('model') \
            .apply(lambda x: model_map[x.name](x)) \
            .droplevel(level='model')
```

```
>>> df
  model  a  b   r
0     a  1  1   2
1     b  5  4   1
2     a  8  6  14
```

Or you can use `np.select`:

```
>>> np.select([df['model'] == 'a', df['model'] == 'b'],
              [model_a(df), model_b(df)])

array([ 2,  1, 14])
```

Comment: How's this do runtime-wise? Does it leverage vectorization or does it run through the dataframe row by row? Note the comment in my original question: "Also because of the size of this data, using apply isn't particularly useful as it would drastically slow down the runtime."

Comment: nvm just tested this works great and vectorized, thanks!